# Regex: extracting some info from text

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataframe, it's part of it

```
Судебный участок № 24 в Павлоградском судебном районе Омской области
Судебный участок № 4 в Горьковского судебного района Омской области
Судебный участок № 5 в Знаменском судебном районе Омской области
Судебный участок № 19 в Оконешниковском судебном районе Омской области
Судебный участок № 9 в Кормиловском районе Омской области
Судебный участок № 29 в Таврическом судебном районе Омской области
Судебный участок № 30 в Таврическом районе Омской области
Судебный участок № 44 Кировского судебного района в городе Омске
```

Desire output

```
Павлоградском судебном районе
Горьковского судебного района
Знаменском судебном районе
Оконешниковском судебном районе
Кормиловском районе
Таврическом судебном районе
Таврическом районе
Кировского судебного района
```

I try to use regex

```
[А-Я][А-Яа-я-]+\s+[а-я\s]*\s*(?:округа|район(?!а|е|у|ого))
```

But it returns only like `Тверской район`. Others are empty.
After it I've changed this expression and try to use

```
[А-Я][А-Яа-я-]+\s+[а-я\s]*\s*(?:округа|район((?!а|е|у|ого).)*)
```

It returns data, but doesn't return endings of word, for example

```
Горьковского судебного район
```

instead

```
Горьковского судебного района
```

I think that using `?!` let use not required words. (for me ending of the words not required).

How should I change this expression to getting desire output?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes. Thank you. I've accepted your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the negative lookahead, you fail all matches where `район` is followed with `а`, `е`, `у` or `ого`.

Use a non-capturing group instead. Replace `(?!а|е|у|ого)` with `(?:а|е|у|ого)` or just `[а-яё]*` to match the word `район` to its end.

The whole regex will look like

```
r'[А-ЯЁ][А-ЯЁа-яё-]+\s+[а-яё\s]*\s*(?:округа|район[а-яё]*)'
```

Or, with word boundaries if you want to only match the strings as whole words:

```
r'\b[А-ЯЁ][А-ЯЁа-яё-]+\s+[а-яё\s]*\s*(?:округа|район[а-яё]*)\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JEOh6B/1).

If you want to use the regex with `str.extract` you need to wrap the pattern with capturing parentheses:

```
df['col'].str.extract(r'\b([А-ЯЁ][А-ЯЁа-яё-]+\s+[а-яё\s]*\s*(?:округа|район[а-яё]*))\b')
```

Comment: I've tried that. If I use it, it doesn't catch `Октябрьского район` in `Судебный участок Октябрьского район`

Comment: @PetrPetrov I doubt you have tried [my solution](https://regex101.com/r/JEOh6B/2) correctly. Try again.

Comment: @PetrPetrov If you use `str.extract`, wrap the pattern with `(...)`.